# How to differentiate $y'''= 1 - 2yy'$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I think I should be doing this (chain rule) but am not sure what the answer would look like,
$$ f(x,y) = 1 - 2yy'$$ then $$ f'(x,y) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} $$?

Comment: So, I'm guessing $y$ is a function of $x$? How does $f$ fit into this?

Comment: Differentiate like $y'''' = -(y')^2 - yy''$? And how does $f$ relate?

Comment: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ is a noun, it doesn't fit after "then" here. It's as if you wrote "$x = 1$ then $x + 1$." You need a verb or something like "$x = 1$ then $x + 1 = 2$."

Comment: I used $f$ to make it easier (for myself that is) to understand the chain rule. $y'''=1 - yy'$ was the result of differentiating $y'' = 3 + x - y^2$. I just want to know how to differentiate $y''$ further.

Comment: I've edited the title. It should read "How to differentiate $y''' = 1 - 2yy'$"

Comment: Hang on, are you trying to solve a differential equation? Because that's how you tagged the question. But based on what you've written it sounds like you're trying to solve an implicit differentiation question which is a different tag.

Comment: I tagged it as "ordinary differential equations" because it forms part of the larger problem area of solving ODE using Taylor series and initial conditions but in order to get successive higher derivatives I need to differentiate $y''=3 + x-y^2$ first, then $y''' = 1 - 2yy'$. Perhaps ODE wasn't the right tag.

Comment: @TheoBendit - yes, $y$ is a function of $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, it seems you want to differentiate $1 + 2yy'$ with respect to $x$.

First, we should simplify using the linearity of the derivative:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} (1 + 2yy') = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} (1) + 2\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(yy') = 2\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(yy'),$$
since $1$ is a constant.

Next, we need the product rule. We have a product of two functions of $x$: $y$ and $y'$. Applying product rule:

$$2\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(yy') = 2y' \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(y) + 2y \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(y') = 2(y')^2 + 2yy''.$$

No chain rule needed in this case! So, differentiating both sides of $y''' = 1 + 2yy'$ yields
$$y^{(4)} = 2(y')^2 + 2yy''.$$

Unfortunately, the non-linearity of the original equation will make power series solutions very difficult!

Comment: You understood correctly. Apologies for being vague.